# What's wrong with this python code that should rename files?

Tags: python

this code is meant to ask for a directory, then list al files in that directory, then rename then to their position in that list, problem is I always get error 2, file not found, while if i print the list it apperently does find the files because the list is not blank.

```
import os, sys    
path = input("input path: ")    
dirs = os.listdir(path)    
for i in range(0,len(dirs)):    
    os.rename(dirs[i], str(i))
```

Given input files, I want to rename the base file name with a number, but preserving the file extension. Thus

Input
'a.txt', 'test.txt', 'test1.txt'

Output
'0.txt', '1.txt', '2.txt'

Comment: If you printed the value of dirs[i], what does it say? My guess is that you need an os.rename(os.path.join(path, dirs[i], str(i)) in there but I'm too lazy to fire up the interpreter

Comment: says: ['a.txt', 'test.txt', 'test1.txt']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, so you do need to add the code from my comment. The problem is [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) is only returning base file names so when the rename is called, it expects to find those files in whatever directory Python thinks it should be in. By adding the os.path.join, it will build out the fully qualified path to the file so the rename will work correctly.

In the comments, OP stated the files got moved up a folder which lead me to believe the rename needed a fully qualified path on second argument. Also, we learned the files should not be renamed from foo.txt to 0 but instead should become 0.txt etc (preserving file extension) This code now

```
import os, sys
path = input("input path: ")
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for i in range(0,len(dirs)):
   # capture the fully qualified path for the original file
   original_file = os.path.join(path, dirs[i])
   # Build the new file name as number . file extension
   # if there is no . in the file name, this code goes boom
   new_file = os.path.join(path, str(i) + '.' + original_file.split('.')[-1])

   print "Renaming {0} as {1}".format(original_file, new_file)
   os.rename(original_file, new_file)
```

Verified with Python 2.6.1

Showing the relevant bits from the command line. You can see the empty files bar.txt and foo.txt are renamed to 0 and 1

```
>>> path = input("Input path")
Input path"/Users/bfellows2/so"
>>> dirs = os.listdir(path)
>>> dirs
['bar.txt', 'foo.txt']
>>> for i in range(0,len(dirs)): 
...  os.rename(os.path.join(path, dirs[i]), str(i))
... 
>>> 
[1]+  Stopped                 python
Helcaraxe:so bfellows2$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 bfellows2  bfellows2   136 Sep  3 20:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  100 bfellows2  bfellows2  3400 Sep  3 20:24 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 bfellows2  bfellows2     0 Sep  3 20:24 0
-rw-r--r--    1 bfellows2  bfellows2     0 Sep  3 20:24 1
Helcaraxe:so bfellows2$ python -V
Python 2.6.1
```

Comment: this code seems to do something though I don't know exactly what as since my files dissapear when I run this... we'll they aren't totally gone as since python tells me they still exist and are renamed by refusing to do it again with new files, but well, I can't acces or find the renamed files

Comment: They are now named 0, 1, 2, etc as your code intended. You've lost file extensions so Windows may be "protecting" you by hiding that fact.

Comment: @billinkc What you have done is almost correct.  What os.path.join is taking the arguments, and concatenating them together placing a '/' between each item.  So os.path.join('1', '2', '3') would result in a sting or '1/2/3'.  This is not quite what you want to happen

Comment: Were you attempting to rename them from a.txt to a.0.txt or something like that? The code as it stands will rename a.txt to 0 (no extension), test.txt to 1 and test1.txt to 2.

Comment: @james huford That'd be true if I had os.path.join(path, dirs) but we are operating on an element of the list with the indexer an not the list itself.

Comment: @billinkc My apologies I misread your answer.  You got my vote :)

Comment: @james huford No worries, my python is several years rusty so I had to go back and verify I really did implement it correctly ;)

Comment: still seems to delete my files when I add .txt extension to the names, atleast the map properties says the map contains 0 files after the operation and my system is set to display hidden files

Comment: @daquicker What *should* it do with the file names. We started with the files you listed in the question's comment, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: okay Expected outcome is from a.txt to 0.txt a,d so on, so I added the .txt extension, seems like the new files are placed in the map from where i run the python file

Comment: What if there is a file named a.b.txt Is the new name 0.txt or 0.b.txt